# truncate field after nth instance of a character postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have fields that look like this:

```
id     field
1      aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd,eee,ffff
```

I am looking to select field up till the third instance of the comma. It would look something like this:

```
aaa,bbb,ccc
```

Is this possible in postgresql?

Answer (score 1):

First, you should not be storing comma delimited values in a string field.  But that said, one method uses `split_part()`:

```
select split_part(field, ',', 1) || ',' || split_part(field, ',', 2) || ',' || split_part(field, ',', 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer to use a regular expression here.  The regex which will match your fixed pattern is:

```
^(\w+,\w+,\w+).*$
```

Using `regexp_matches`, this becomes:

```
select regexp_matches(field, E'^(\\w+,\\w+,\\w+).*$')
from yourTable
```

Note: I tested this query on my local Postgres and it runs fine, q.v. this screen capture

[image]

Comment: thank you for your response, and not commenting on how data gets fed to me ;-)

Comment: sorry-- i have to unaccept this. doesn't seem to be working. getting a 'function doesn't seem to exist error.' checking the regex to see what might be the issue..

Comment: The query works fine for me locally.  Are you sure you copied it correctly?